# Как загрузить изображение с локального диска в программу на PyQt5?

Tags: pyqt5

Как загрузить изображение с локального диска в программу на PyQt5?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] вашего приложения на PyQt5 и лучше расскажите куда вы хотите вставить изображение.

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/698191169699446854/843439684037902336/1.png?width=1500&height=844

Comment: не надо ссылок, опубликуйте в теле вопроса ваш код обычным текстом.